# What is the purpose of a reset button on power strips?

Tags: ac, mains

I'm just curious why would someone put a reset button on power strips in which don't usually implement any digital circuitry. I'm sure it's not for discharging any capacitors, since power strips don't have any. [image: reset button (black)]

Comment: The state of power plug and strip receptacle on your picture looks really dangerous to use. The circuit breaker and its reset button won't prevent you from house fire. Stop using it.

Answer (score 7):

The reset button is part of a circuit breaker which should trip if the power strip is overloaded.  The reset button allows you to reset the breaker.  It has nothing to do with a microcontroller or other electronics.

A panel-mount circuit breaker:
[image]

Comment: But the switch in question is just a loose momentary push button switch that feels soft to the touch. If it's a breaker, it must be stiff and it has to be a two way on off switch, just like common breakers.

Comment: Maqny breakers designed to be installed in equipment, including in power strips, look, to the user, as a simple pushbutton.  If you open the powere strip (not that I'm recommending you do), you should find that the body of the "button" has a current rating shown. see the photo I added to my answer.

Comment: @YudhiG. Re, "...it has to be a two way on off switch..." No. It doesn't. The circuit breaker in the picture in this answer does not provide any means for you to manually switch it off. You can switch it back on after it trips by pressing the red button, but the only way it ever gets switched off is by an over-current trip.

Comment: Could you provide a diagram? [This one](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fqph.fs.quoracdn.net%2Fmain-qimg-29eb009319afdefa164a47796d0672c8&f=1&nofb=1) (NTC+MOV) seems the classic surge protection circuit but lacks of the push-button.